# Adding an IFERROR to a formula, to hide #DIV/0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add an IFERROR to this formula.

```
=SUM('July 2021'!E6;'August 2021'!E6;)/NB('July 2021'!E6;'August 2021'!E6;)
```

Ideally, if the aforementioned formula ends up being a division by 0 (which happens a lot at the moment), I would like it to display "0", instead of #DIV/0!.

I did try, but no success.

```
=IFERROR(('July 2021'!E6;'August 2021'!E6;)/NB('July 2021'!E6;'August 2021'!E6;);0),SUM('July 2021'!E6;'August 2021'!E6;)/NB('July 2021'!E6;'August 2021'!E6;)
```

Went through a lot of help pages, but couldn't find a solution ...

Thank you in advance !

J-

Comment: `=IFERROR(SUM('July 2021'!E6;'August 2021'!E6;)/NB('July 2021'!E6;'August 2021'!E6;);0)`

Comment: Worked !
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Just throw an iferror around the whole formula with whatever you want to display whenever this occurs (and change your semi-colons to correct syntax -',' depending upon your region - [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/list-separator), courtesy @BigBen - comments):

```
=IFERROR(SUM('July 2021'!E6,'August 2021'!E6,)/NB('July 2021'!E6,'August 2021'!E6),0)
```

Comment: Note that this needs a `;` instead of `,` as the last separator to be consistent.

Comment: That's new to me - what happens if it's not? (have you tried it in excel?)

Comment: @BigBen (in fact, I'm not entirely sure the semi-colon works - this is incorrect syntax for Excel - I just threw it into Office 365 compatible version of Excel and it wouldn't process the very first instance of ";" within the summation formula... retract your pvs comment as its misleading (unless you're able to convince me otherwise?)

Comment: @BigBen - I DID NOT know that this was locale-dependent.  Indeed sir, you have convinced me - revision should be consistent - agreed?

Comment: All good. My apologies if that came across harshly or too forceful. All that really matters is that OP's problem is solved, thank you for posting this answer!

Comment: You didn't come across too harshly at all - good that we rectified the soln. thanks for your assistance/direction - I'm surprised that I'm still learning something new about Excel every so often (after almost 2 decades! But there are always new features - locale has probably been around for that long though! :)